# How to make a for loop to go through two arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to make a for loop that goes from 0 to 180, and then back again to -180. I tried the following:

```
for a=0:1:180 && 179:-1:-180
```

but this is not possible in MATLAB.

I have tried to use the `&&` and `||` statements, but both don't work. I don't know any other ways to combine the two arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what you really *want*. Is it a loop that goes from 0 to 180 and then back again to -180? The `&&` operator is a logical AND, which only works on scalar values, so what you wrote this is definitely not possible.

Comment: i want to go from 0 to 180 and then from 180 to -180, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the `&&` and `||` operators. What you want is the following:

> Go from 0 to 180 in steps of 1 AND then go from 180 to -180 in steps of -1.

However for any two statements `A` and `B` (both `A` and `B` need to be *scalar* values!), the command `A && B` does the following:

> Return True, if both `A` and `B` are True, return False otherwise.

This is a *logical* AND, while you want to go through your first array AND through your second array after that. Though both is some kind of *AND*, you can't use `&&` for your purpose.

Now, when you call `for a=0:180`, MATLAB does the following:

1. Create the vector `0:180`, that is `[0, 1, 2, ..., 180]`.
2. Run all the content inside the loop for each element in the vector created in 1).

So, what you want to do is create an array that contains the numbers `[0, 1, 2, ..., 179, 180, 179, 178, ..., -179, -180]`. You can do that by *concatenating* the arrays `[0:180]` and `[179:-1:-180]`. You should read about concatenation in MATLAB in their [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html). So, long story short, you for loop should be

```
for a=[0:180, 179:-1:-180]
```